# Integrating a custom Twitter Bootstrap theme in OrchardCMS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Does anyone have a guide or checklist on implementing a custom Twitter Boostrap theme into Orchard CMS?

I have a site running on Orchard CMS 1.6 and I've installed the [Twitter Bootstrap Theme](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Bootstrap) from the gallery.  Now I'm looking to take a custom bootstrap design (3rd party) and integrate it into this theme.  I would assume that this would be pretty standard for any custom bootstrap theme...  basically just a mapping from the normal bootstrap file structure to where the various js/css/html files and snippets would go in the Orchard theme layout.

If this doesn't already exist, and you think it would help you out, let me know and I'll do a blog post (if I don't get an answer here).

Answer (score 1):

And it seems there's a real bootstrap port for orchard nowdays. see:

http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can check [BootTheme](http://www.boottheme.com/) it contains a lot of free themes for Bootstrap. Just replace the CSS files with the theme you download. Then you got yourself a new theme.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately that's not exactly what i'm looking for.  I already have a fully customized responsive design built on bootstrap from {wrap}bootstrap that I would like to use.  I just need to integrate it into Orchard.